# Transformation of 2D profile to 3D coordinates

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

I am sure that answer for similar questions have being given more than one thousandth times, but correct answer that suits my needs I still haven't found.

Currently I am developing simple 3D app. My task is to draw [beams](http://images.wisegeek.com/steel-i-beam.jpg) in 3D space.

What is my input:

1. Profile of beam, which is represented with set of 2D coordinates.
   For example, that profile is a triangle with coordinates A (-1, 0),
   B (0, 1), C (1,0).
2. Two 3D points P (1,2,3) and D (4,5,6). This points represent axis of my beam.
3. **edit:** OZ axis of 2D profile must lay at the same plane as OZ axis of 3D space do.

What I need to get:

I need to get from set of 2D coordinates set of 3D coordinates. In other words, my profile coordinates need to be placed on the 3D plane, which is perpendicular to PD axis.

Please, help me to solve this problem.

Comment: You need more input to specify a unique solution. With what you have so far, the profile may be rotated around the axis, and there is no tellin which rotation is the one you want. I assume that you want to origin of the 2d plane to coincide with your 3d axis, but if not, you might have to clarify that point as well.

Comment: Really, origin of my profile is coincident to 3d axis.

Comment: You cannot have the plane of the profile be both perpendicular to the $PD$ axis and parallel to the $OZ$ axis unless $PD$ is parallel to $OZ$, which it is not in your example.

Comment: Sorry, I am again with mistake. ^^ Hope my new edit adds some clarity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's see. You are looking for a local coordinate system such that the $OX$ axis of the plane is at the same time orthogonal to the $PD$ axis of extrusion and to the $OZ$ axis of the 3d coordinate system. You can obtain a vector which is parallel to two given vectors by computing the cross product, although you'll want to scale the resulting vector back to unit length.

$$ w_1 = \begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\1\end{pmatrix}\times(P-D) \qquad
v_1 = \frac{w_1}{\lVert w_1\rVert} $$

For the second coordinate direction, you want to be orthogonal to $v_1$ and again orthogonal to $PD$, so you could use

$$ w_2 = w_1\times(P-D) \qquad v_2 = \frac{w_2}{\lVert w_2\rVert} $$

Then any point $(x,y)$ in the profile plane will correspond to the line connecting $P+xv_1+yv_2$ to $D+xv_1+yv_2$.

Note that the above answer is only characterized by orthogonality requirements, but don't mention orientation. For each of the two cross products, you might change the order of operands, resulting in the opposite (i.e. negative) vector. I guess we could start analyzing which signs you obtain from the above computation, and which signs you actually want. But I suggest you simply give it a try, and flip the order if you find some sign to be different than what you want it to be.

## Example

In your question, you provided some example coordinates. To make this example more illustrating, I'll use a different point in the plane, though, taken from your comment below.

$$ P = \begin{pmatrix}1\\2\\3\end{pmatrix} \qquad
D = \begin{pmatrix}4\\5\\6\end{pmatrix} \qquad
M = \begin{pmatrix}4\\5\end{pmatrix} $$

Then you get

$$ v_1=\frac{1}{\sqrt{18}}\begin{pmatrix}3\\-3\\0\end{pmatrix}=
\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\begin{pmatrix}1\\-1\\0\end{pmatrix} \qquad
v_2=\frac{1}{\sqrt{486}}\begin{pmatrix}9\\9\\-18\end{pmatrix}=
\frac{1}{\sqrt6}\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\-2\end{pmatrix} \\[6ex]
P+4v_1+5v_2 =
\begin{pmatrix}1\\2\\3\end{pmatrix} +
\frac{4}{\sqrt2}\begin{pmatrix}1\\-1\\0\end{pmatrix} +
\frac{5}{\sqrt6}\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\-2\end{pmatrix} =
\begin{pmatrix}
1 + \frac{4}{\sqrt2} + \frac{5}{\sqrt6} \\[2ex]
2 - \frac{4}{\sqrt2} + \frac{5}{\sqrt6} \\[2ex]
3 - \frac{10}{\sqrt6}
\end{pmatrix} $$

So that ugly vector would be one of the endpoints of your line.

Comment: I already [answered a similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23212131/1468366) today.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I am little confused with notation 
$$
P + xv1 + yv2
$$
How can I get the standard for me $(x,y,z)$ view?

Comment: @HnatiukDmitriy: Well, $v_1$ and $v_2$ are unit length vectors, with three components each, computed as outlined above. You simply scale them by $x$ resp. $y$, which means multiply each component by that factor. Then you add them using vector addition, which means simple component-wise addition.

Comment: You mean that I need to add coordinates of P to scaled $v1$? Can you provide simple sample. Assuming that $v1$ is $(1,2,3)$ and some point M on 2D profile is $(4,5)$ and P is $(7,8)$.

Comment: @HnatiukDmitriy: You need $v_1$ to have unit length, and you need $P$ to be a 3d point, so your example from the comment doesn't work that easily. But I've updated my post to include an example.

Comment: So that ugly vector would be one of the endpoints of your line.

This is vector, or 3D representation of 2D point $M$?

Comment: To me, that vector *is* the 3D representation of the 2D point $M$. Or, to be more precise, the representation associated with the endpoint $P$ of your line, you get another representation at $D$. I don't see your distinction.

Comment: Thanks a lot for a help. My rate is lower 15th so I can't vote for your answer :(